# Check if application was opened by tapping a notification

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios8, apple-push-notifications

I am having some problems with the behavior push notifications in my app.

If the app is not running (not even in the background), when I touch a notification I can parse its payload and do a custom action, by reading the "launchOptions" dictionary.

When my app is running in the background, I am not being able to detect when a user foregrounds the app by tapping the notification, as application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler: is called immediately in the background, and when I foreground the app I have no way to check if it was done by tapping the app icon or the notification.

I know this is possible because Facebook's Messenger app does this - if I tap the notification it brings me to the chat, else it brings me to where I was previously.

Thanks.

Comment: Kinda clunky, but why not just use `NSUserDefaults` and set a key?

Comment: I only want an action to happen if the user opens the app using the notification - not tap the icon. FB Messenger does this... So it's possible.

Comment: Yeah, and I'm saying in the `-application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:` just set a boolean and check for it when the app comes back to the foreground.

Comment: Still won't work for what I need. I don't want the push action to occur if the user taps the app icon and not the notification itself.

Answer (score 1):

If the user taps the app icon, `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler` does not get called.

If they tap the notification, `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler` does get called and `application.applicationState` will be `UIApplicationStateInactive`.

Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22085855/426839) for a code snippet that you can use to quickly see this in action to have it make more sense.

Also, to achieve your goal be sure to do any updating of views when the application state is `UIApplicationStateInactive`, not `UIApplicationStateBackground`. The application state will be `UIApplicationStateBackground` when the push notification comes in. The application state will be `UIApplicationStateInactive` only when the user launches the app by tapping the notification.

I've seen a lot of answers with if statements like

```
if (application.applicationState != UIApplicationStateActive) { ... }
```

but that won't allow you to distinguish between a push notification being delivered and the user tapping a notification.