# get data from push notification when app is closed in iOS and app not running in background

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification

When receive a push notification and my application is totally closed, how can handle this info?

Only can get data from `NSDictionary` on this method **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:** or

**didReceiveRemoteNotification:**

for example: **when the user open the application how get data from the push notification?, and not when the user open the push notification directly.**

Is there a method that responds and detect if a notification has not been read?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You'll want to implement

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult result))handler
```

This will launch your app if needed, then you'll want to save the data somewhere so when the user next's starts the app you grab the data and do something with it.

[From Apples Doc's:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:)

> Discussion
>
> Use this method to process incoming remote notifications for your app.
>   Unlike the application:didReceiveRemoteNotification: method, which is
>   called only when your app is running in the foreground, the system
>   calls this method when your app is running in the foreground or
>   background. In addition, if you enabled the remote notifications
>   background mode, the system launches your app (or wakes it from the
>   suspended state) and puts it in the background state when a push
>   notification arrives. However, the system does not automatically
>   launch your app if the user has force-quit it. In that situation, the
>   user must relaunch your app or restart the device before the system
>   attempts to launch your app automatically again.

Just look into the method and I'm certain you'll figure it out :)

I did a quick google, these look like they will help:

SO example: [didReceiveRemoteNotification: fetchCompletionHandler: open from icon vs push notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22085234/didreceiveremotenotification-fetchcompletionhandler-open-from-icon-vs-push-not)

The first tutorial i saw on it: http://hayageek.com/ios-background-fetch/

Comment: I have a quick question. If I close the app from the multitask screen will I still be able to receive a notification? Because on my end, seems like I can't receive a notification when I close the app.

Comment: @BooRanger Thank you so much for your answer !!!!! Love You ( Not appropriate though )

Comment: @BooRanger thanks, a lot I spent looooooooong time looking for this