# detect app opened from push notification (background fetch)

Tags: ios, objective-c, notifications, push

I use UIBackgroundFetchResult to catch push notifications as below code...i use content availability = 1 also to detect in background mode

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)   (UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler {
```

**Push is coming and is executed on here while app is active or background mode always 
BUT when i opened push,i cannot detect whether app is opened from push or not because it always enters if state**

```
 if ( (application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateInactive || application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateBackground)  && (NotiType == 1 || NotiType == 2))
    {

}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [didReceiveRemoteNotification: fetchCompletionHandler: open from icon vs push notification](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22085234/didreceiveremotenotification-fetchcompletionhandler-open-from-icon-vs-push-not)

Answer (score 1):

You can check whether your app is launched from APNS (Apple Push notification service), from app delegate method

```
application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:
```

In which you can check whether app launched from notification or not like this,

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    if (launchOptions != nil) {
          // Launched from push notification
          NSDictionary *notification = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];

    }
}
```

If your app is in background, this method will not invoke. for that you can check in another method with this way,

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
    if ( application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateInactive || application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateBackground  )
    {
         //opened from a push notification when the app was on background
    }
}
```

HTH, Enjoy Coding !!

Comment: never hits second function because i use content avaibility = 1 it is working on 
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)   (UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler {

Comment: Not getting you, can u elaborate it further.

Comment: i dont use didreceiveremotenotification i use fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^) (UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler {